# How to find out if LND opening pending channels has a confirmation onchain?

Tags: transactions, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, transaction-id, ln-opening-channels

After typing `lncli pendingchannels` I get a channel_point number, and when I put channel_point txid to check if it was confirmed onchain 
by typing:

```
bitcoin-cli gettransaction "txid insert"
```

I get an error:

```
error code: -5
error message:
Ivalid or non-wallet transaction id
```

How can I  see if whoever opened (pending state) channel to me has a confirmation on chain?

Answer (score 1):

`lncli pendingchannels` gives a `pendingChannelRespnse` which might have the `pending_open_channels` parameter. This contains an array of  `PendingOpenChannel` objects.

According to [the documentation](https://api.lightning.community/#pendingopenchannel) they should have a parameter `confirmation_height` which is the height of the blockchain at which the funding TX has enough confirmations (the max of your and your channel partners threshold)

See 
[image]

So from `bitcoin-cli` you figure out the current height and take the difference to see how many confirmations are still needed.

I guess if you don't get a pendingopenchannel object you don't have confirmations yet.

Comment: Thank you I see "confirmation_height": 0,

Comment: its just I've been waiting for several days for someone opening channel to me but its always pending.I looked at the mempool and its empty therefore if a person who opened a channel to me set 1sat/byte then it should be confirmed but I cannot even see the transaction onchain. I am confused.

Comment: I have been contacted by another person running c Lightning having a similar issue. and I have the idea that you have a power that does (deliberately?) not follow the channel establishment protocol. Can you see from the logfiles at which state of the channel establishment protocol you are in? Which BOLT 02 messages have been exchanged so far? Maybe your node did not send `funding _signed` message?  (obviously I am guessing here as I don't have full information)

Comment: I don't use BOLT

Comment: I have no idea what BOLT means my misunderstanding. So I don't know how to do all that Rene.

Comment: Well I was asking for your logfile and in particular the entire that concern the channel opening protocol. I have just released a video about channel closure on my channel that might help you to understand the channel protocol BOLT 02 https://youtu.be/Gyt4nxRHy04. BOLT stands for basics of lightning vtechnologies and is the protocol specification that all implementations are following. This I am pretty sure you unknowingly are using the BOLTs (:

Answer (score 0):

To get the TX, using

> lncli pendingchannels

You'll get a JSON document and the channel_point is your TX (Minus the :1 at the end)